# incorrect Pop control behavior in WPF application?

Tags: wpf, popup, wpf-controls, togglebutton, 2-way-object-databinding

I have added on Popup control which is binded with placement target of Toggle button on MainWindow.xmal file in WPF.  IsChecked property of Toggle button is binded with IsOpen property of Popup control to have in sync behavior.
When we run and maximize the MainWindow of application, click on the toggle button. It will open pop control. Till this point it is normal behavior.
But when we switch with Shift+ Tab button to another window, Popup control is still open. It should be part of running application. It should be in the background with MainWindow. But it appear on front window of highlighted application.

```
 <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Popup Name="popCntrl" AllowsTransparency="True" Placement="Left" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=btnToggle}" >
                <Border BorderBrush="AliceBlue" BorderThickness="1">
                    <StackPanel Width="200" Height="150" Background="Aqua">
                        <TextBlock Text=" This is Pop up window content. Should be part of running application"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </Popup>
            <ToggleButton Grid.RowSpan="2" Name="btnToggle" Height="20" Width="60" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                          IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=popCntrl ,Path=IsOpen, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Background="Brown" />

    </Grid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to set `StaysOpen` property on `Popup` to `false`. When you set that, popup will close itself when it loses focus.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.staysopen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> When the StaysOpen property is set to true, Popup stays open until it
>   is explicitly closed by setting the IsOpen property to false. When
>   StaysOpen is false, the Popup control intercepts all mouse and
>   keyboard events to determine when one of these events occurs outside
>   the Popup control.

Comment: Yes, That definitely work if we set StayOpen property to true. But When window is again activated with Alt+Tab , pop will not be in open state .User has to click again to open it. So this is kind of unwanted behavior.

Comment: I guess, you would have to do a bit of focus management by yourself. Once you get the focus back to your windows, you may have to re-set the open/closed status on the Popup.